# Laravel 5 Database Like query on a array

Tags: php, laravel

I have been working on a laravel advance search filter where a user can input several field in a form and on submit it generates data table for given fields. and if fields are empty then it just shows all the records from database (unsets the filter).

```
 public function advanced_search(Request $request)
{

    //user submitted data in post
    $post = $request->all();

  /*

    filter array keys are defined here
    e.g first_name, last_name

  */

    $simple_filter = array(
        "first_name" => "",
        "last_name" => "",
        "email" => "",
        "company_name" => "",
    );
    foreach ($simple_filter as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($post[$key]) && ($post[$key] != null) && !empty($post[$key])) {
            $simple_filter[$key] = $post[$key];
        } else {
            //user didn't send this field in post data so removing this from filter list

            unset($simple_filter[$key]);
        }
    }

    $query = DB::table('contacts')->where($simple_filter)->get();
    return DataTables::of($query)
        ->toJson();
}
```

Now this code is working fine. But requirements are changed. This code only return the exact details. Now I want to show record even if substring matches. (LIKE %data$). How can I modify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`orWhere()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses) if you want to find contacts where one of the fields is `like` a given form input. Or use [`where()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses) if you want to use all the form input elements to filter contacts:

```
public function advanced_search(Request $request)
{
    $query = Contact::query();
    $fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'company_name'];
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if ($request->filled($field)) {
            $query = $query->orWhere($field, 'like', '%' . $request->get($field) . '%');
        }
    }
    return DataTables::of($query->get())->toJson();
}
```

Also, you're doing a lot of redundant checks. Just use the `->filled()` method instead. It will return `false` if a field is empty, or doesn't exist or `null`.

> If you would like to determine if a value is present on the request and is not empty, you may use the filled method

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: This is ok, but maybe he only wants entries that match all of the filled fields, and not any that matches any filled field.

Comment: This is nice. And working. I'll go with this one. Thanks for replying here. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the query before the loop and add all [`where`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses) filters in the loop. The second parameter of the [`where`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses) function can be the comparer, in your case: `like`.

```
$query = DB::table('contacts');

foreach ($simple_filter as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($post[$key]) && ($post[$key] != null) && !empty($post[$key])) 
    {
        $query = $query->orWhere($key, 'like', '%' . $value . '%');
    }
}

return DataTables::of($query->get())->toJson();
```

Comment: I tried this but its not working properly. Its giving me all the records every time. But I get the idea.. I'll try to make it work somehow. Thanks for replying here